# Limit Row Height on rows with Lookup Column

Tags: list, css, lookup-column

I have a SharePoint list in which there are three columns that are lookups from another SharePoint list. The list has custom CSS (below) that limits the row heights on all columns except the lookups. I need a way to limit the row height on the list to include these three columns. The rest of the columns cut off at the max height and text wrap according to the CSS below.

```
<style>
div.ms-rtestate-field {
   max-height: 4.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
tr.ms-alternating {
    Background-color: #eeeeee;
}
TABLE.ms-listviewtable TBODY TR TD DIV { HEIGHT: 20px; OVERFLOW-Y: auto; }
<style>
```